# Hector_SLAM, How to read sensor data from remote interface

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, beaglebone, hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working on two approaches to do generate map scans from a remote device.

The basic hardware set-up:

At the robot is a BeagleBone/Ubuntu with Hokuyo and UM6-IMU w/Ethernet connection to Access Point.

At the command center is a control PC running Hector_SLAM

Approach 1: Have the control PC/Hector_SLAM poll the robot for needed sensor data.

Approach 2: Stream the sensor data from the robot to the control PC. Hector_SLAM reads sensor data at the control PC.

Approach 2 will cut radio traffic as only transmissions from the robot end are needed so I believe this is the preferred method, but???

A) Does the streamed data need to go to a folder from which Hector_SLAM pulls the data? How??

or

B) Can Hector_SLAM read the streaming data directly? How??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57422/hector_slam,-how-to-read-sensor-data-from-remote-interface/) by [TJump](https://answers.ros.org/users/2785/tjump/) on ROS Answers with karma: 160 on 2013-03-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you have both computers on the same network, you can subscribe to laser messages seamlessly (as far as you have [properly configured](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines) your system). The only problem may be the bandwidth available, due to the large size and frequency of laser messages.

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2013-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1